# Organisational project management for Open Source work

Tags: open-source, project-management, github

As a small company we do work a lot on open source code. (http://Github.com/agiliq). I want a tool which we can use to do project management and task tracking for our open source code and work.

### Features

1. Should integrate well with Github (See below)
2. Commits to Github should update the project management tool.
3. Logging a ticket in Github should start a task here. Should work for closing too.
4. Public mode so tasks and discussion here should be visible on public site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).  We use it at my work and it works pretty well.  I have yet to come across something else better.

Answer (score 4):

you might want to check out atlassian's tools, in fact their products are not for free but open source project can use it without any cost .

http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/licensing-faq.jsp#open-source

and they support github also : https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/9502

Comment: Do they offer these for their hosted offering too?

Comment: Found out that they do. 2 weeks is too long a wiat though. "For JIRA Studio, please allow 2 weeks for your open source license application to be processed. For all other products, please allow approximately 3 working days."

Answer (score 2):

There are several issue-tracking tools which integrate directly with GitHub. From the [feature description page](https://github.com/features/projects):

> Already have a favorite issue tracker?
>   No problem! We're here to improve your
>   workflow, not replace it.
>
> GitHub integrates with: FogBugz, Trac,
>   Lighthouse, and Pivotal Tracker

If one of those works for you, that seems like the obvious solution.

Like other posters, I am also a fan of [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/), but I'm not sure how you get the issues integration with Redmine without doing extra work (see below). [There is a plugin](http://eddieringle.com/easily-integrate-a-github-repository-with-redmine-using-the-github-hook-plugin/) that allows you to sync the GitHub repository with your local Redmine repo, so that part is covered. There is also an [excellent discussion](https://github.com/tswicegood/fabric/wiki/GitHub-vs.-Redmine) comparing the feature sets of the two.

Finally, you can roll your own bit of code to hook up your favourite tool. GitHub has a pretty [comprehensive API](http://develop.github.com/), with [libraries](http://develop.github.com/p/libraries.html) in many languages. Here's the [Issue Tracker API](http://develop.github.com/p/issues.html). Using this, you could probably set up an issues trigger in Redmine quite easily. A simple solution would be to write a small piece of code that fires off an email to Redmine when the GitHub API detects an incoming issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse (with PyDev for Python), you have a number of [mylyn connectors](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Mylyn_Extensions) in development right now.
Initially tracked by [bug 272812](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=272812), a GitHub mylyn connector is now monitored in [bug 303009](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=303009), with the **[org.eclipse.mylyn.github](https://github.com/devsprint/org.eclipse.mylyn.github)** project.

Comment: I am looking at project management tool for collaboration and task tracking. I dont think Mylyn fits that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Assembla - task tracking and collaboration. Free for open source projects. www.assembla.com

Comment: They are a fair tool, but they dont have "Should integrate well with Github"